# Vue material component md-select required attirbute not working

Tags: html, vue-material

I'm using https://vuematerial.io/components/select for an admin dashboard and using the html validations. Except for `md-select` HTML validations are working. For `md-select` even if we add `required` attribute and fill the data it is still asking to fill the data.

```
<md-field>
   <label>User type</label>
   <md-select v-model="userType" name="userType" id="userType" required>
      <md-option v-if="$loggedInUserType == 'admin'" value="admin">admin</md-option>
      <md-option  v-if="$loggedInUserType == 'admin'" value="company">company</md-option>
      <md-option  v-if="$loggedInUserType == 'company'" value="staff">staff</md-option>
   </md-select>
</md-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like Vue Material is adding `readonly="readonly"` attribute to the `<select>` element behind the component. When there's a `readonly` attribute the `required` attribute is ignored. [see here](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/blob/67677a2ffa1028df4aa1b9e21ba4bf3211fd9c4d/src/components/MdField/MdSelect/MdSelect.vue)

my solution is to create an `opacity: 0` input right behind the `md-select` tied to the same `v-model` and set as `required`

Comment: I couldn't test it anymore since the admin panel theme was full of these kinds of bug s I have deleted that theme it's been 4 months.